# Microsoft Graph APIでユーザー情報を取得したい

Tags: microsoft-graph

ユーザーのオブジェクトIDを用いて、ユーザー名(displayName)を取得したいと考えています。

### 試したこと

1. Azure Active Directoryの設定

アプリの登録 > 該当のアプリを選択 > APIアクセスの許可
において、User.Readの設定

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2. access_tokenの取得

下記のAPIでaccess_tokenを取得

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

3. Microsoft graph APIの実行

上記access_tokenを使用して、下記APIを実行するとエラーになってしまいます。

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ユーザーオブジェクトID}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一覧取得でも同じ結果になってしまいます。

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

他に設定すべき点や、間違っていそうな点はありそうでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0):

こちらは自己解決していました。

`User.Read` から `User.Read.All` (アプリケーションの許可が必要なやつ) に変えて、
エンタープライズアプリケーションに移動　> アクセス許可 > xxxxxxに管理者の同意を与えます
を行ってから、同じAPIを実行しました。